# Malformed regular expression in ColdFusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

My password should contain at least one special character from the list below.

`@ % + / ! # $ ^ ? : , { } ( ) [ ] ~` - _.`

I tried this in ColdFusion using the below code but it is throwing hard error saying:

> Malformed regular expression "@%+/!#$^?:,{}()[]~`-_"

```
<cfif REFind("@%+/!##$^?:,{}()[]~`-_",arguments.myPassword) IS 0>
 // some business logic
</cfif>
```

Could any one help me fix this issue?

Comment: Try `"[@%+/!#$^?:,{}()[\\]~\`_.-]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is malformed because `` [`-_] `` [forms an invalid range](https://regex101.com/r/Si68K8/1).

Use

```
<cfif REFind("[@%+/!##$^?:,{}()[\\]~`_.-]",arguments.myPassword) IS 0>
```

Here, note that

- a `[...]` is a character class that matches 1 char form the defined sets/symbols inside the class
- `-` is at the end of the character class and is thus treated as a literal `-`
- `]` inside the character class MUST be escaped with a literal `\`

Comment: the error gone when I gave this regex. But it gives me correct answer when I give the regex as [@%+/!##$^?:,{}()\[\]~`_-].... Is there any difference?

Comment: Is the `]` inside the character class escaped? It must be escaped. What is the string you test against? Note you do not need to double `#` symbol, it is enough to use just one.

Comment: # must be doubled otherwise CFML compiler will throw error..  Test sttring : 2Password##

Comment: Ok, I see no issue with the input string. The `"[@%+/!##$^?:,{}()[\\]~\`_.-]"` regex finds *partial* matches, it will also return true with the `abcd^hm` string.